# Compare 2 strings in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, strpos

I'm in trouble because i can't figured it out how to find my answer.
I'm creating a wordpress website and i have a search engine

I've created an option in my admin panel and code something to write in my option table, but my problem is now

firstly i grab my options from my database with

```
$mysynonymvalue = get_option( 'synonym-custom' );
```

I precise that it returne to me something like this ( mango, apple, banana)(this is an example of course)

My Url is something like this :

http://supserwebsite/wordpress/?sfid=2675&_sf_s=toto

Or this

http://superwebsite/wordpress/?sfid=2675&_sf_s=virtualisation cloud devops

so i've created a variable to catch the queries

```
$motsclefs3= $_GET['_sf_s'];
```

Now i want to compare the string $mysynonymvalueconvert with $motsclefs3 to find if it match so i write

```
                            if (strpos ($mysynonymvalue, $motsclefs3) ){
                            echo '<script >
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                    $(".vc-tabs-li:nth-child(2)").get(0).click();
                                });
                            </script>';
                            }                           
                            else{
                                echo '
                        <script >
                                $(document).ready(function(){
                                    $(".vc-tabs-li").get(0).click();
                                });
                            </script>';

                            };
                        };
```

The solution seem to work correctly but i can't have the first result, it coompare indeed with all the results but not my first one.

And it doesn't work so fine because with only one letter it return a match ( for example 'a')

Any solution ?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `strpos` as an equality check? `===` is cleaner and faster. Also, your echo statements are commented out, but seem to go over two lines, meaning your PHP snippet is invalid.

Comment: I removed the foreach that was useless in fact, but i use     strpos to compare string elements, because $mysynonymvalue can have multiple data and not just one, i also rework my echo, but still not what i expected ^^'

Comment: So you have `mango, apple, banana` as a string value, and now you are trying to check whether it contains f.e. `apple`? Well then `explode` the first value so that you get a proper array with the individual words, and then use `in_array` to check.

Comment: In fact i tried something like $myvariable = explode(' ', $motsclefs3); and rework my "if" to look something like "   if (in_array($myvariable, $mysynonymvalue))   " but same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far i move up a bit !So i came with this

I still have

```
$mysynonymvalue = get_option( 'synonym-custom' );
$mysynonymvalueconvert = preg_split('/[,]+/',$mysynonymvalue);
```

To grab my words from my database and to convert it into an array.
(the point of this is to get elements that were wrote by an user elsewhere on the admin panel of wordpress)

I also still have

```
 $motsclefs3= $_GET['_sf_s'];
```

To grab my actual queries ( that will serv me to compare ). I precise that it return me a string. To be more specific, an URL like this (http://mywebsite/wordpress/?sfid=2675&_sf_s=examen) return me (in string) "examen".

Now my point is still to compare if

```
  $motsclefs3;
```

is inside

```
 $mysynonymvalueconvert
```

So i've created a "for" loop like this

```
for ($i = 0;  $i <= count($mysynonymvalueconvert); $i++){                                                    
                                if(in_array($motsclefs3, $mysynonymvalueconvert)){                                 
                                    echo'yes';
                                    break;
                               }
                               else{
                                    echo 'no';
                                    break;
                               };
                            };
```

But i'm still blocked, this return "yes" only if it match with the first element from

```
 $mysynonymvalueconvert
```

So any ideas to help me ?

Thanks!

Comment: Nevemind Guys !  My problem was in my database ^^'. In fact the code above is correct, but my databse wasn't registered the good data. So i just change my databse to work properly and it work well, sorry for disturbing and thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

*provided url(s) are not accessible.

**Solution:**
Create a dictionary of option from db and then search the element which you are looking.

Comment: It's an example URL, i can't grant you access to ^^' sorry

Comment: i can't just compare these two elements without to create this ? I also tried something to create arrays of my results from $mysynonymvalue but compare 2 arrays seem not working cause of the data that are not inn the same number on each results

Comment: Direct comparing the array won't work. if you have array_1 and array_2 then start iterating the array_2 and check while iterate the element is exist or match in array_1   if exist then break the loop. I think you need element to element comparision. (correct me if I am wrong).